# Azure Blob download file via API in Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage, java-17

I am trying to publish an API in Java to download files from Azure blob if exists but getting exceptions at openQueryInputStream.

```html
BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.getBlobClient(fileQueuePath + "/" + fileName);
            boolean blobExists = blobClient.exists();
            if (!blobExists) {
                     return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND)
                        .entity("File not available in the specified path.")
                        .build();
            }

            InputStream is = blobClient.openQueryInputStream();

            return Response.ok(is)
                    .header("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
                    .build();

        }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the exception including relevant stack trace as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you're not actually creating the stream for the download correctly.

You might want to try the following changes:

```
if (!blobExists) {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND)
        .entity("File not available in the specified path.")
        .build();
}
try (ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
    blobClient.downloadStream(outputStream);
    final byte[] = outputStream.toByteArray();
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new 
    ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(bytes);
    return Response.ok(outputStream)
                    .header("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
                    .build();

} catch(IOException e) {
    // Do something with the exception?
}
```

If you'd like, you can do the same by using a `BlobInputStream`:

```
try (BlobInputStream blobStream = blobClient.openInputStream()) {
    blobStream.read();
    // Now return this stream.
} catch (IOException e) {
    // DO something?
}
```